# Java Persistence: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Basically I'm implementing a PDS (Personal Data Sheet) so I have tables such as Client (employee), Personalinfo, Otherinfo.

Client table structure:

```
idClients, name, institute, username, password, usertype
```

Personalinfo table structure:

```
idPersonalInfo, agencyno, bloodtype, status, citizenship, address, idClients
```

I can add client successfully but when I'm trying to add/update personalinfo, I get

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

In personalinfo class I have this line also:

```
 @JoinColumn(name = "idClients", referencedColumnName = "idClients", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

In Clients class I also included:

```
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "clients")    
    private Personalinfo personalinfo;
```

But I can't figure out why I'm getting constraint violations.

```
Error Code: 1452
Call: INSERT INTO personalinfo (...) VALUES (...)
    bind => [7parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(com.profiling.database.Personalinfo[ idPersonalInfo=null ])
```

EDIT:

```
if (personal != null) {
          .....
            personal.setClients(client);
            personal.setIdPersonalInfo(client.getIdClients());

            EntityManager em = emanager.getEntityManager();
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(personal);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Personal Info Updated Successfully");
        } else {
            personal = new Personalinfo();
            ....
            personal.setClients(client);
            client.setPersonalinfo(personal);
            EntityManager em = emanager.getEntityManager();

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(personal);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "New Personal Info Save");
        }
```

**EDIT**
Client Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Clients.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Clients c"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Clients.findByIdClients", query = "SELECT c FROM Clients c WHERE c.idClients = :idClients"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Clients.findByFirstName", query = "SELECT c FROM Clients c WHERE c.firstName = :firstName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Clients.findByGender", query = "SELECT c FROM Clients c WHERE c.gender = :gender"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Clients.findByLastName", query = "SELECT c FROM Clients c WHERE c.lastName = :lastName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Clients.findByMiddlename", query = "SELECT c FROM Clients c WHERE c.middlename = :middlename"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Clients.findByNameExtension", query = "SELECT c FROM Clients c WHERE c.nameExtension = :nameExtension")})
public class Clients implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idClients")
    private Integer idClients;
    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "Gender")
    private String gender;
    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "Middlename")
    private String middlename;
    @Column(name = "NameExtension")
    private String nameExtension;
    @Column(name = "Institute")
    private String institute;

    //value added
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "userType")
    private String userType;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Workexpe> workexpeList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Ratingscore> ratingscoreList;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "clients")
    private Familyback familyback;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Civilservice> civilserviceList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Staffscore> staffscoreList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Referenceinfo> referenceinfoList;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "clients")    
    private Personalinfo personalinfo;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "clients")
//    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private Otherinfo otherinfo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Trainingprog> trainingprogList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Children> childrenList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Specialskills> specialskillsList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Educback> educbackList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idClients")
    private List<Voluntarywork> voluntaryworkList;

    public Clients() {
    }

    public Clients(Integer idClients) {
        this.idClients = idClients;
    }

    public Integer getIdClients() {
        return idClients;
    }

    public void setIdClients(Integer idClients) {
        this.idClients = idClients;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getMiddlename() {
        return middlename;
    }

    public void setMiddlename(String middlename) {
        this.middlename = middlename;
    }

    public String getNameExtension() {
        return nameExtension;
    }

    public void setNameExtension(String nameExtension) {
        this.nameExtension = nameExtension;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Workexpe> getWorkexpeList() {
        return workexpeList;
    }

    public void setWorkexpeList(List<Workexpe> workexpeList) {
        this.workexpeList = workexpeList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Ratingscore> getRatingscoreList() {
        return ratingscoreList;
    }

    public void setRatingscoreList(List<Ratingscore> ratingscoreList) {
        this.ratingscoreList = ratingscoreList;
    }

    public Familyback getFamilyback() {
        return familyback;
    }

    public void setFamilyback(Familyback familyback) {
        this.familyback = familyback;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Civilservice> getCivilserviceList() {
        return civilserviceList;
    }

    public void setCivilserviceList(List<Civilservice> civilserviceList) {
        this.civilserviceList = civilserviceList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Staffscore> getStaffscoreList() {
        return staffscoreList;
    }

    public void setStaffscoreList(List<Staffscore> staffscoreList) {
        this.staffscoreList = staffscoreList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Referenceinfo> getReferenceinfoList() {
        return referenceinfoList;
    }

    public void setReferenceinfoList(List<Referenceinfo> referenceinfoList) {
        this.referenceinfoList = referenceinfoList;
    }

    public Personalinfo getPersonalinfo() {
        return personalinfo;
    }

    public void setPersonalinfo(Personalinfo personalinfo) {
        this.personalinfo = personalinfo;
    }

    public Otherinfo getOtherinfo() {
        return otherinfo;
    }

    public void setOtherinfo(Otherinfo otherinfo) {
        this.otherinfo = otherinfo;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }



    @XmlTransient
    public List<Trainingprog> getTrainingprogList() {
        return trainingprogList;
    }

    public void setTrainingprogList(List<Trainingprog> trainingprogList) {
        this.trainingprogList = trainingprogList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Children> getChildrenList() {
        return childrenList;
    }

    public void setChildrenList(List<Children> childrenList) {
        this.childrenList = childrenList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Specialskills> getSpecialskillsList() {
        return specialskillsList;
    }

    public void setSpecialskillsList(List<Specialskills> specialskillsList) {
        this.specialskillsList = specialskillsList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Educback> getEducbackList() {
        return educbackList;
    }

    public void setEducbackList(List<Educback> educbackList) {
        this.educbackList = educbackList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Voluntarywork> getVoluntaryworkList() {
        return voluntaryworkList;
    }

    public void setVoluntaryworkList(List<Voluntarywork> voluntaryworkList) {
        this.voluntaryworkList = voluntaryworkList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idClients != null ? idClients.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Clients)) {
            return false;
        }
        Clients other = (Clients) object;
        if ((this.idClients == null && other.idClients != null) || (this.idClients != null && !this.idClients.equals(other.idClients))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.lastName + ", " + this.firstName;
    }

    public String getInstitute() {
        return institute;
    }

    public void setInstitute(String institute) {
        this.institute = institute;
    }

}
```

**Personalinfo**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "personalinfo")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByIdPersonalInfo", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.idPersonalInfo = :idPersonalInfo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByAgencyNumber", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.agencyNumber = :agencyNumber"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByBloodType", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.bloodType = :bloodType"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByCellphone", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.cellphone = :cellphone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByCevilStatus", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.cevilStatus = :cevilStatus"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByCitizenship", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.citizenship = :citizenship"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByDateofBirth", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.dateofBirth = :dateofBirth"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByEmailAdd", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.emailAdd = :emailAdd"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByGsis", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.gsis = :gsis"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByHeight", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.height = :height"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByPagibig", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.pagibig = :pagibig"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByPermanentAddress", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.permanentAddress = :permanentAddress"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByPhilHealth", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.philHealth = :philHealth"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByPlaceofBirth", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.placeofBirth = :placeofBirth"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByResidentialAddress", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.residentialAddress = :residentialAddress"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findBySssNo", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.sssNo = :sssNo"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByTelephone1", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.telephone1 = :telephone1"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByTelephone2", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.telephone2 = :telephone2"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByTin", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.tin = :tin"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByWeight", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.weight = :weight"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByZipcode1", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.zipcode1 = :zipcode1"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Personalinfo.findByZipcode2", query = "SELECT p FROM Personalinfo p WHERE p.zipcode2 = :zipcode2")})
public class Personalinfo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "idPersonalInfo")
    private Integer idPersonalInfo;
    @Column(name = "AgencyNumber")
    private String agencyNumber;
    @Column(name = "BloodType")
    private String bloodType;
    @Column(name = "Cellphone")
    private String cellphone;
    @Column(name = "CevilStatus")
    private String cevilStatus;
    @Column(name = "Citizenship")
    private String citizenship;
    @Column(name = "DateofBirth")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateofBirth;
    @Column(name = "EmailAdd")
    private String emailAdd;
    @Column(name = "GSIS")
    private String gsis;
    @Column(name = "Height")
    private String height;
    @Column(name = "Pagibig")
    private String pagibig;
    @Column(name = "PermanentAddress")
    private String permanentAddress;
    @Column(name = "PhilHealth")
    private String philHealth;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "Picture")
    private byte[] picture;
    @Column(name = "PlaceofBirth")
    private String placeofBirth;
    @Column(name = "ResidentialAddress")
    private String residentialAddress;
    @Column(name = "SssNo")
    private String sssNo;
    @Column(name = "Telephone1")
    private String telephone1;
    @Column(name = "Telephone2")
    private String telephone2;
    @Column(name = "Tin")
    private String tin;
    @Column(name = "Weight")
    private String weight;
    @Column(name = "Zipcode1")
    private String zipcode1;
    @Column(name = "Zipcode2")
    private String zipcode2;
    @Column(name = "IdClients")
    private String idClients;

    @JoinColumn(name = "idClients", referencedColumnName = "idClients", insertable = false, updatable = false)
//    @JoinColumn(name = "idClients", referencedColumnName = "idClients")
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Clients clients;

    public Personalinfo() {
    }

    public Personalinfo(Integer idPersonalInfo) {
        this.idPersonalInfo = idPersonalInfo;
    }

    public Integer getIdPersonalInfo() {
        return idPersonalInfo;
    }

    public void setIdPersonalInfo(Integer idPersonalInfo) {
        this.idPersonalInfo = idPersonalInfo;
    }

    public String getAgencyNumber() {
        return agencyNumber;
    }

    public void setAgencyNumber(String agencyNumber) {
        this.agencyNumber = agencyNumber;
    }

    public String getBloodType() {
        return bloodType;
    }

    public void setBloodType(String bloodType) {
        this.bloodType = bloodType;
    }

    public String getCellphone() {
        return cellphone;
    }

    public void setCellphone(String cellphone) {
        this.cellphone = cellphone;
    }

    public String getCevilStatus() {
        return cevilStatus;
    }

    public void setCevilStatus(String cevilStatus) {
        this.cevilStatus = cevilStatus;
    }

    public String getCitizenship() {
        return citizenship;
    }

    public void setCitizenship(String citizenship) {
        this.citizenship = citizenship;
    }

    public Date getDateofBirth() {
        return dateofBirth;
    }

    public void setDateofBirth(Date dateofBirth) {
        this.dateofBirth = dateofBirth;
    }

    public String getEmailAdd() {
        return emailAdd;
    }

    public void setEmailAdd(String emailAdd) {
        this.emailAdd = emailAdd;
    }

    public String getGsis() {
        return gsis;
    }

    public void setGsis(String gsis) {
        this.gsis = gsis;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getPagibig() {
        return pagibig;
    }

    public void setPagibig(String pagibig) {
        this.pagibig = pagibig;
    }

    public String getPermanentAddress() {
        return permanentAddress;
    }

    public void setPermanentAddress(String permanentAddress) {
        this.permanentAddress = permanentAddress;
    }

    public String getPhilHealth() {
        return philHealth;
    }

    public void setPhilHealth(String philHealth) {
        this.philHealth = philHealth;
    }

    public byte[] getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(byte[] picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public String getPlaceofBirth() {
        return placeofBirth;
    }

    public void setPlaceofBirth(String placeofBirth) {
        this.placeofBirth = placeofBirth;
    }

    public String getResidentialAddress() {
        return residentialAddress;
    }

    public void setResidentialAddress(String residentialAddress) {
        this.residentialAddress = residentialAddress;
    }

    public String getSssNo() {
        return sssNo;
    }

    public void setSssNo(String sssNo) {
        this.sssNo = sssNo;
    }

    public String getTelephone1() {
        return telephone1;
    }

    public void setTelephone1(String telephone1) {
        this.telephone1 = telephone1;
    }

    public String getTelephone2() {
        return telephone2;
    }

    public void setTelephone2(String telephone2) {
        this.telephone2 = telephone2;
    }

    public String getTin() {
        return tin;
    }

    public void setTin(String tin) {
        this.tin = tin;
    }

    public String getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getZipcode1() {
        return zipcode1;
    }

    public void setZipcode1(String zipcode1) {
        this.zipcode1 = zipcode1;
    }

    public String getZipcode2() {
        return zipcode2;
    }

    public void setZipcode2(String zipcode2) {
        this.zipcode2 = zipcode2;
    }

    @MapsId
    public Clients getClients() {
        return clients;
    }

    @MapsId
    public void setClients(Clients clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }

    public String getIdClient() {
        return idClients;
    }

    public void setIdClients(String clients) {
        this.idClients = clients;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idPersonalInfo != null ? idPersonalInfo.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Personalinfo)) {
            return false;
        }
        Personalinfo other = (Personalinfo) object;
        if ((this.idPersonalInfo == null && other.idPersonalInfo != null) || (this.idPersonalInfo != null && !this.idPersonalInfo.equals(other.idPersonalInfo))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.doscst.profiling.database.Personalinfo[ idPersonalInfo=" + idPersonalInfo + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is with the insert, but you should show us the code making that insert, or even the SQL itself.

Comment: Most likely the row you are trying to insert violated a foreign key constraint.  Does its parent even exist?

Comment: please post the personalinfo and client class.seems there is a issue in the mappings.

Comment: @Tim yes, I save first the client and I'm trying to insert personal info.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you try with this in `PersonalInfo` class and check.

```
@OneToOne 
@JoinColumn(name = "idClients")
private Clients clients;
```

Comment: Tried but I get this error:  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.

Comment: can you share the exception or stacktrace.

Comment: Exception [EclipseLink-48] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [personalinfo.IdClients].  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.